# Get the ownercontrol of a graphics object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, gdi+, gdi

Is possible to know the ownercontrol of a `Graphics` object?

In this method I'm passing the graphics object of a control to a custom method, together with the control's width and height:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) _
Handles PictureBox1.Paint

    Me.MyMethod(g:=e.Graphics, Width:=sender.width, Height:=sender.height)

End Sub
```

But I would like to avoid passing the width and height parametters to my method (or else passing the control), instead that `MyMethod` should find the control width/hight just with the graphics object, in case this could be possibly.

Something like this pseudocode:

```
private sub mymethod(byval g as graphics)

    dim _width as integer = g.GetControlWidth
    dim _height as integer = g.GetontrolHeight

end sub
```

Comment: your question has a flaw in its premise: just because you acquire the graphics object in a control's paint event, doesnt mean Graphics is related to it.  `System.Drawing.Graphics` is not directly related to the control.  `MyMethod(g As Graphics, ctl As Control)` is as close as you will get and that will still lose other `e` event args in other paint related events (e.DrawBackGround, e.DrawFocusRect, e.PaintParentBackground etc).

Comment: Thanks plutonix then this is solved, post an answer if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has a flaw in its premise: just because you acquire the Graphics object in a control's paint event, doesnt mean they are related or that you can get the control from Graphics.  `System.Drawing.Graphics` is just not directly related to `Control`. About as close as you can get is:

```
MyMethod(g As Graphics, ctl As Control)
```

Even then, for many other painting and drawing events, you will lose other vital information in those `e As xxxEventArgs`  such as `e.DrawBackGround`, `e.DrawFocusRect`, `e.ClipRectangle` (sometimes more important than the control's size) `e.PaintParentBackground` and so forth.

There *are* times when you can call a common procedure - such as drawing a 3D rectangle, or borders etc - but those are usually of value when a procedure depends on one or more calculated args common to each control or thing being painted/Drawn:

```
Protected Sub Draw3DRect(g As Graphics, rect As Rectangle, bRaised As Boolean)

Protected Sub DrawBorder(g As Graphics, R As Rectangle)

Private Sub DrawThumb(g As Graphics, R As Rectangle)
```

The actual drawing or painting of whatever is all the same once the Rectangle is defined, but the Rectangle is not necessarily related to the Control's Size.